# Java 8 Stream "collect and group by" objects that map to multiple keys

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have the following objects:

```
public class Item {
    String value;
    List<Person> owners;
    Person creator;
}

public class Person {
    String name;
    int id;
    Person manager;
}
```

now i have the a list containing 3 Item objects:

```
i1 -> {value="1", owners=[p1, p2, p3], creator=p4}
i2 -> {value="2", owners=[p2, p3], creator=p5}
i3 -> {value="3", owners=[p5], creator=p1}
```

the Person objects are as follows:

```
p1 -> {manager=m1, ...}
p2 -> {manager=m2, ...}
p3 -> {manager=m3, ...}
p4 -> {manager=m2, ...}
p5 -> {manager=m1, ...}
```

I want to group the stream of Item objects based on managers of the owners and creator. The result `Map<Person, List<Item>>` should look like:

```
{
  m1: [i1, i2, i3],
  m2: [i1, i2],
  m3: [i1, i2]
}
```

I think using Stream and Collector APIs, I can make the map from Item to managers, `Map<Item, List<Person>>` first, then reverse the mapping. But is there any way to make the mapping I want using Stream and Collectors only?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think, this is only possible with an intermediate “pair” value to remember the association between a person/manager and the originating item. In absence of a standard pair type in Java’s standard API, we have to resort to `Map.Entry` which comes closest to a `Pair` type:

```
Map<Person, List<Item>> map = list.stream()
  .flatMap(item->item.getOwners().stream()
    .map(p->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(p.getManager(), item)))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

after improving it using `import static` we get

```
Map<Person, List<Item>> map = list.stream()
  .flatMap(item->item.getOwners().stream().map(p->new SimpleEntry<>(p.getManager(), item)))
  .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

It results in

```
m1: [i1,i3]
m3: [i1,i2]
m2: [i1,i2]
```

which differs because first, the standard map has no defined ordering, second, I think you made a mistake regarding you expectation as `m1` is not associated with `i2` in your example data.

Comment: I also need the mapping for creators of the list of Items. m1 -> p5 -> creator of i2. But I think I can modify your solution a little bit and do .map(item -> item.getCreator()...) and then merge the corresponding List<Item> for the same Person key (manager).

Comment: Actually what I also want is mapping based multiple properties. It is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508253/java-8-streams-map-the-same-object-multiple-times-based-on-different-properties?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Such scenarios are well supported by my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which enhances standard Stream API:

```
Map<Person, List<Item>> map = StreamEx.of(list) // create an enhanced stream of Item
                // create a stream of Entry<Item, manager>
                .cross(item -> item.getOwners().stream().map(Person::getManager))
                // swap keys and values to get stream of Entry<manager, Item>
                .invert()
                .grouping();
```

Internally it's similar to @Holger solution.