# Java stream collect to map with multiple keys

Tags: java, key, java-stream, collect

I thought I was getting pretty good at Java 8 streams, but then...

I have a `Foo` interface:

```
public interface Foo {
  String getKey();
  Stream<Bar> bars();
}
```

I know I can collect a `Stream<Foo>` into a `Map<String, Foo>` using the key of each:

```
Map<String, Foo> foosByKey = fooStream.collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Foo::getKey, Function.identity()));
```

But what if I want to collect them into a `Map<Bar, Foo>`? In other words, for each `Foo` in the steam, I want to put that `Foo` in the map keyed to every one of the `Bar` instances returned by `Foo.bars()`. Where do I start?

Comment: No, you have it backwards. A `Map<Bar, Foo>` would imply a one-to-one mapping between `Bar` and `Foo` instances. Consider `Map<CreditCardNumber, Person>` or `Map<ISBN, Book>`, where a person can have multiple credit cards and a book can have multiple ISBNs. Nothing complicated here.

Comment: I do understand the meaning, but I didn't want to get hung up on points that are a bit ancillary. Whether a mapping is bidirectional depends on whether the graph is directional. A Java `Map` is a unidirectional, so you can't map back---which is why Guava has a `BiMap`, for instance. I think you wanted to say that the _relationship_ is one-to-one---in this case the _relationship_ is many-to-one (`Bar`-`Foo`). But again this is all sort of beside the point---things to debate over a beer. The summary is that each `Foo` can have many `Bar`, and I want to map `Bar` to `Foo`. Cheers!

Comment: Indeed, we can close with the statement that each `Foo` can have many `Bar` and that all `Bar`s are distinct and, well, I think [Sotirios’ answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37956805/2711488) contains an appropriate solution. Is there anything that stops you from accepting his answer, that we should address?

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more elegant and concise; without explicit intermediaries. I'll hold out for a little longer and see if anyone comes up with any tricks.

Comment: I tried with a specialized collector, then I realized that this not only is less readable, in the end it only replaces the explicit instantiation of `Map.Entry` instances with implicit instantiation of capturing lambda instances, so there is no improvement at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086686/java-8-stream-collect-and-group-by-objects-that-map-to-multiple-keys), you'll want extract the `Bar` values from each `Foo` and create pairs of them. Once you have the pairs, you can collect them into a `Map`. For example,

```
Map<Bar, Foo> map = fooStream.flatMap(foo -> foo.bars().map(bar -> new SimpleEntry<>(bar, foo)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

We use `SimpleEntry` here because it's available (Java doesn't have a simpler `Pair` type). You could write your own to be more specific.

Comment: The `SimpleEntry<>` use is cool---I hadn't realized Java had something at least similar to a `Pair`. Overall though I was hoping for something a little more compact, but this may be the best we can get. I'll leave it for a while longer to see if we get any other options.

Comment: Java 9 will add the possibility to use `Map.entry(bar, foo)` to construct value-based, immutable entries in a more concise way.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a new collector for that. One simple implementation (that always creates HashMap's of ArrayList's; no downstream support) could be:

```
public static <T, K>
Collector<T, ?, Map<K, List<T>>> multiGroupingBy(
        Function<? super T, Collection<? extends K>> multiClassifier) {
    return Collector.of(
            HashMap::new,
            (map, entry) -> {
                multiClassifier.apply(entry)
                        .forEach(
                                key -> map
                                        .computeIfAbsent(key,
                                                __ -> new ArrayList<>())
                                        .add(entry));
            },
            (map1, map2) -> {
                map2.forEach(
                        (key, list) -> map1
                                .computeIfAbsent(key,
                                        __ -> new ArrayList<>())
                                .addAll(list));
                return map1;
            });
}
```

Then you could call:

```
fooStream.collect(multiGroupingBy(Foo::bars));
```