# Java 8 streaming: How to convert list of objects to a list of its selected properties

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class

```
class Person {
   // get/set omitted for simplicity
   public String firstName;
   public String lastName;
}
```

also I have a list of such objects

```
List<Person> list ...
```

I need to convert with the streams the following

```
List<Person> list ...
List<String> firstLastNames = list.stream()....
```

So my List firstLastNames will contain first and last names in this list. So.

```
System.out.println(firstLastNames); // will give me -> "John", "Smith", "Jessica", "Jones".. etc.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about something like this

```
stream.stream().flatMap(p -> Stream.of(p.firstName, p.lastName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: First, upvote. everything is ok, but you should remove `new Object(...)` expression.

Comment: Downvoted for now, good answer and I want to upvote but currently it doesn't compile. The question looks like there should be a duplicate but I couldn't find one.

Comment: yes, Stream.of is something I was looking for. Edited the response by removing new Object(...)

Comment: Oleg, that's why I posted this question because couldn't find the answer. Not a first day on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: @walv That's good to know, lots of people who've been here for even more days post without bothering to look. There is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28508931/1398418 question which is similar and also has an alternative solution. `list.stream().collect(ArrayList::new, (l,p) -> {l.add(p.firstName); l.add(p.lastName);},ArrayList::addAll);`

Comment: @Oleg: the alternative of the linked answer is specifically for collecting into a map, where the `flatMap` variant needs a temporary holder for two values. Since this is not the case when collecting into a `List`, using the simpler `flatMap` approach is preferable.

Comment: @Holger Sorry but you're wrong. This is straight from the javadoc `stringStream.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add,ArrayList::addAll);` I haven't tested it but I'm willing to bet that it will be faster. No need to create new Stream for every `Person` and flatMapiing all of them.

Comment: @Oleg: you will hardly ever measure any significant performance difference. But if you care for the tiniest bits of performance, a loop will be even faster. If you want to use the stream API, using `flatMap(…).collect(Collectors.toList())` is straight-forward. Besides, which javadoc are you talking about? The inner workings of `Collectors.toList()`, as well the actual returned `List` implementation type, is intentionally unspecified and might be even faster than `ArrayList` in a future version.

Comment: @Holger The [javadoc of the collect method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) they gave an example with a list. Nothing is more straightforward then using a method the way it was intended to be used. I really don't know why you struggle with this, please look at the javadoc and think for a couple of minutes before your next reply.

Comment: @Holger Also reread the answer I linked to and read the comment from freaking Brian Goetz if something is still not clear. Quote from him "On the other hand, using collect() as Misha shows is designed to handle this case".

Comment: @Oleg: this is an *example* helping you to understand the usage. That doesn’t imply that you should always roll out your manual collector despite the fact that there is a build-in collector for the purpose. Now *you* should think yourself, why does `Collectors.toList()` exist, if the recommendation really was to always re-implement that operation yourself?

Comment: @Oleg: *Again*, the linked answer is about collecting into a **`Map`**. Also, Brain Goetz compares the approach with a wrong `reduce` approach. At no point does he recommend to always roll out your own custom collector instead of using the builtin one. And no-one said that a re-implemented collector was wrong, it’s just recommended to use the existing one when possible instead of reinventing the wheel. As it is always.

Comment: @Holger `Collectors.toList()` exists to make your life simpler when it solves your problem in a good way. Why don't you think yourself and tell me why is there a `collect` method that accepts 3 functions if you're never supposed to use it?????? What is the difference between List and Map(in this context)???? Why is this solution good for a map and not for a list???????????????????

Comment: @Holger Nobody reinvents any wheels in either solution. With flatMap there are 2 completely unnecessary extra steps which are needed before you can use `Collectors.toList()` with using `collect` directly you just use it directly. If this would've been a bad solution Brian Goetz would have said something. Some deductive reasoning is required to reach that conclusion.

Comment: @Holger, @Oleg
IMO, using Stream.of is the right way to go. Alternative solution proposed by @Oleg requires business logic, in other words I have to know I have to call exaclty method `add` (not a big deal but) while Stream.of() was designed for the cases like this one. Also think about the case when I need to process this list of strings further using the same streaming flow.

Comment: @walv Those are good reasons. And overall I also probably like the solution in the answer more. \@Holger's reasons were ridiculous.

Comment: @Oleg: my reasons are exactly the same as walv’s. I said, it is the *straight-forward* solution. That already implies needing less thinking about it, e.g. when changing the stream chain to something else. As using the standard idiom always is. And I already explained why that specific map operation has been implemented with a custom collector. Using `flatMap` there would require a holder object, either an additional custom class or abusing `Map.Entry`, as Java has no standard tuple type. In contrast, combining `flatMap` with `Stream.of` is exactly the intended use case.

Comment: @Holger No, you said "specifically for collecting into a map" nothing in that answer indicates that it has anything to do with it. The alternative is between preparing your stream for mutable reduction by a standard Collector or implementing the accumulator yourself. Misha described the advantages of both options starting with " It is immediately clear to me what it does..." and "However, Alternative 2 has a huge ..." none of them has anything to do with it being a Map and not a List. If **you** think that it's an important distinction that's fine it doesn't make it "specific for a map".

Answer (score -3):

If you want a true properties object (java.util.Properties) you can do something like below. Note that since your using properties, you won't be able to have duplicate records this way.

```
 public static void main(String args[])
{
    // make some people
    Person john = new Person("John", "Smith");
    Person mary = new Person("Mary", "Richards");

    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    people.add(john);
    people.add(mary);

    Properties peopleProps = new Properties();
    for (Person person : people)
    {
        peopleProps.setProperty(person.getfName(), person.getlName());
    }

    System.out.println(peopleProps);

}
```

Comment: This has literally nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Also: this uses the firstname as a key in a key-value structure. Having two ``Person``s with the same firstname messes everything up.

Comment: An answer that technically answers the **title** is not related to the question, you need to read all of it and answer the actual question.

Comment: understood, I'm curious why one would want a list of names in this way though, might there be a better data structure than a list? I'm still working in java 7 myself so maybe there's something I'm not aware of, but what if the list has like 2000+ "records", how would you actually use it?

Comment: I don't know why OP needs this and depending on his needs there might be a better data structure but 2000 Persons with lets say 10 letters for each first and last name(deliberate exaggeration) will be less than 80 KiB. Not a problem on modern computer and you can use it in any way you like.