# Reduce for parallel stream without combiner executes by several threads correctly. When should I use combiner at this case?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I have read following about:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22814174/2674303

and I made resolution that combiner uses only in parallel stream for correct merge accumulator results. one accumulator instance on each thread.

Thus I made resolution that reduce without combiner will not work correctly.

To check this I have wrote following example:

```
   Person reduce = Person.getPersons().stream()
                .parallel() 
                .reduce(new Person(), (intermediateResult, p2) -> {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    return new Person("default", intermediateResult.getAge() + p2.getAge());
                });
        System.out.println(reduce);
```

model:

```
public class Person {

    String name;

    Integer age;
    ///...

    public static Collection<Person> getPersons() {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Vasya", 12));
        persons.add(new Person("Petya", 32));
        persons.add(new Person("Serj", 10));
        persons.add(new Person("Onotole", 18));
        return persons;
   }
}
```

As you can see I don't provide combiner
sample output:

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
Person{name='default', age=72}
```

I have executed application several times and always I see correct result.

Please, explain how does reduce working for parallel stream if combiner is not provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case your accumulator works as combiner as well. This is a shorthand when reduction type is the same as stream element type. Thus

```
myStream.reduce(identity, accumulator);
```

Is fully equivalent to

```
myStream.reduce(identity, accumulator, accumulator);
```

You can even check the source code of these methods in [OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#ReferencePipeline.reduce%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.util.function.BinaryOperator%29):

```
@Override
public final <R> R reduce(R identity, BiFunction<R, ? super P_OUT, R> accumulator, 
                          BinaryOperator<R> combiner) {
    return evaluate(ReduceOps.makeRef(identity, accumulator, combiner));
}

@Override
public final P_OUT reduce(final P_OUT identity, final BinaryOperator<P_OUT> accumulator) {
    return evaluate(ReduceOps.makeRef(identity, accumulator, accumulator));
}
```

The three-argument version is more flexible as the reduction operation may produce an object of another type. In this case you cannot use two-argument reduction, because you don't provide a rule how to combine two elements of the resulting type. However when resulting type is the same, accumulator and combiner work on the same object type, thus if it's associative, it should be just the same operation.

Answer (score 4):

You *have* specified a combiner. In this case, the combiner function is identical to your *accumulator* function.

This is always possible, if the result type is identical to your stream element type.

Compare with reduction by summing up the values, `a+b+c+d` might evaluated in parallel by calculating `(a+b)+(c+d)`. Here, the accumulator is the addition, which is the same operation as the combiner function which processes the intermediate results of `(a+b)` and `(c+d)`.

This example also shows that, unless there is a type conversion involved, it would be strange if you need a different combiner function as the associativity constraint of the accumulator function implies that it is normally sufficient as a combiner function. Keep in mind, that it should be irrelevant, whether the stream calculates, `a+b+c+d`, `(a+b+c)+d`, `(a+b)+(c+d)` or `a+(b+c+d)`.

Answer (score 0):

3-argument `reduce` exists for a somewhat uncommon situation that looks like this:

Imagine that instead of reducing a stream of `Person`s into a `Person`, you had a different intermediate value like `PopulationStats`.

```
class PopulationStats {
  // make new stats that includes this person
  PopulationStats addPerson(Person p) {
    return new PopulationStats(........);
  }

  // make new stats that combines this and other stats
  PopulationStats addStats(PopulationStats other) {
    return new PopulationStats(........);
  } 
}
```

In a case like that, the 3-argument `reduce` serves to avoid the intermediate step of making a `PopulationStats` for each `Person` before reducing.

```
PopulationStats stats = people.stream()
  .reduce(new PopulationStats(), PopulationStats::addPerson, PopulationStats::addStats);
```

Comment: A more natural example would be `numberStream.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (bd,n) -> bd.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(n.doubleValue())), BigDecimal::add)`…